Logic Gates with BJT-Transistors (Higher Output Voltage)
I want to build some parts of a simple 4-bit computer (AU, LU, registers, what else comes to my mind). The problem is that with every logic gate/transistor the voltage is dropping. So how can I achieve, that the voltage remains the same/is increased?
I tried already different voltages but with the same result.
I know that energy is lost (converted to internal energy) every time, but a BJT transistor has a base were the "missing" electrical energy should come from, am I right?
I am using the 2N2222A NPN transistor. (Or should I use another one?)

In all of them the losing Voltage thing appears. (And in any other tried arrangement)

Please include a schematic of relevant portions of your circuit, especially specific gates that are losing voltage. A proper transistor circuit for this application should not be "losing voltage", but there are commonly used configurations that suffer from this issue and are unsuitable for such logic gate use.

No, the transistor base does not provide any "missing" energy, it just controls the collector to emitter current.

No s.c.h.e.m.a.t.i.c.s, no clarity.

All of your drawings need two things: a resistor between Vcc and the rest of the circuit, and resistors on the bases. As shown, the only thing that will happen is that the transistors will short Vcc to GND.

One old logic family (current mode logic) has this problem, as well.   The solution is to have a logic margin large enough to tolerate a few of the lossy 'gate' elements, and then require a latch or flip-flop.   Latches and flip flops and multivibrators and Schmitt triggers all use positive feedback circuitry, and will generate full output with small inputs.   Positive feedback is the key, and it doesn't require a second type of transistor.

From what you've said, seems like you're building a logic type called 'resistor-transistor logic', or RTL (not to be confused with Register Transfer Level language like Verilog or VHDL.) You're in good company: this was the kind of logic used to send the Apollo astronauts to the moon and back.
Here are some examples of basic RTL gates in Falstad (simulate them here):

As you look at these, notice two things. First, RTL uses a pull-up resistor on its output to make a logic '1'. Second, RTL inputs are transistor bases, which require current to drive them to '1'.
Since that base current is supplied with a pull-up resistor, an output connected to base inputs will lose logic-1 voltage. And with RTL that's ok, so long as enough current is making its way to the bases to turn on the transistors fully (that is, 'saturated'.) The more inputs you have connected, the more current is drawn from the pull-up, and the more 'loss' you will see.
In RTL then, the output pullup resistor and power supply limit the number of devices you can drive with one output. The term for this limit is called fan-out. This slide deck goes in to some detail about this. The tl; dr version: RTL fan-out is about 3 loads, which by today's standards is rather poor.
You can improve RTL fan-out by using a smaller pull-up resistor, at the expense of additional power dissipation.
If 'losing voltage' (it does make the logic harder to observe), and low fan-out are a concern for you, note that MOS logic (NMOS, CMOS) requires no gate current. MOS driving MOS will not 'lose voltage' because the pullup will be able to take the output all the way to Vcc since there's no DC load on it. Therefore, MOS logic it has much higher fan-out than RTL or DTL, about 20-40 gates.
For your build then, you can simply replace those 2N2222's with a 2N7002 n-FETs.
Here's those same three basic gates (and another useful one: XNOR), using n-FETs instead (simulate it here):

These will work exactly the same, logic-wise, but you won't 'lose voltage': logic 1's will be VCC, logic 0's will be GND. Another benefit: you can also increase the size of your pull-up to reduce power.

One more thing. In between those ancient bipolar families (RTL, DTL) and MOS was a widely used logic family called TTL. It's still in use today. TTL works a bit differently than RTL or DTL: it has active pull-up and pull down which helps with fan-out, and its inputs use pull-down current rather than pull-up. TTL has a higher fan-out (10-20 gates). However, it's more complex than RTL or DTL.
I don't recommend trying to build TTL out of discretes, especially when you can just choose n-MOS FETs with a pull-up to do that.

Clearly your "gates" are not properly designed. Read about the the definitions of the logic levels VOH VOL VIH VIL and noise margin.
